# Rpg where the world is ending

Tags: product-identification

I remember reading some months ago about an rpg where the world is ending, and the characters try and make peace with their past, or accomplish some other personal goal before the end.
I remember it was very narrative focused, and ideal for a one shot, but i can't for the life of me remember the name.

Does my vague description ring any bells?

Comment: Was this a specific game system? Was it a campaign/oneshot for D&D or one of the other more well known game systems? Without that kind of information, I doubt anybody could ever help you figure out what you're thinking of.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This sounds like [ten candles](https://cavalrygames.com/ten-candles). It is storytelling focused, all characters die in the end and the description of the game also states:

> It is a game about being pushed to the brink of madness and despair, searching for hope in a hopeless world, and trying to do something meaningful with your final few hours left.

The format of the game also makes it ideal for one-shots

Comment: I can personally attest that "ideal for one-shots" is a huge understatement. Ten Candles is probably the best one-shot I've ever played. My usual group's tone tends towards Monty Python rather than Game of Thrones, but Ten Candles expertly maintains a serious, yet enjoyable tone.